# How to synchronise the value of properties in different objects using NSNotification or alternative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, gamekit, nsnotification

I have a "Game Kit Manager" class that tries to authenticate the player into game center as soon the app starts up.

My gameKitManager class has a property `@property bool isAuthenticated` that is updated each time the status is changed.

```
-(void)authenticatedPlayer:(GKLocalPlayer*)localPlayer
{
    self.isAuthenticated = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Local player authenticated into game center");
}

-(void)disableGameCenter
{
    self.isAuthenticated = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:UNAUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Disabled game center");
}
```

I have a view controller that has a label indicating whether the user is signed into game center or not (e.g.: the text would say "signed in" or "signed out".

- **How do I set the initial value of the label? Even if I register to receive notifications, it will only work for future status changes, but will not help me set the initial value. If I set the initial value by reading `isAuthenticated`, its possible that I could receive a notification just after reading isAuthenticated, and thus "overwrite" the correct value (see scenarios /illustrations below). How do I keep the label and isAuthenticated in sync?**

Scenario

- label.text = if(gameKitManager.isAuthenticated)label.text = "Yay!"; (eg:Yes)
- gameKitManager authentication status changes (e.g.:No)
- register view controller for changes in auth.
- Result -> Label.text doesn't have the correct value.

Scenario 2

- register view controller for changes in auth.
- (1) label.text = if(gameKitManager.isAuthenticated)label.text = "Yay!"; (e.g.:Yes)
- gameKitManager authentication status changes (e.g.:No)
- Notification triggers method to update label.text. Completes before (1)
- (1) Completes, but overwrites value read during notification
- Result -> Label.text doesn't have the correct value.

I don't know how to repro this scenario, but I think it is possible and want to design for it.